# $scope is not visible in ng-click handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following controller

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.var = 1;

        $scope.updateData = function () {
            debugger; // <-- $scope is undefined here!
        }
    }]);
```

dirrective is as follows...

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('formL', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                items: '=info'
            },
            controller: 'formCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'js/form/form.html'
        };
    });
```

Template is the following

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="formCtrl as controller">
    <input type="button" value="BTN" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateData()">
</form>
```

That does not seem to be the common problem (at least I did not found something simmilar in Google and on SO), when I hit button and get into controller `$scope` is `undefined`. And at the same time `this` is equal to `$scope` as it should be.

What should I do to make `$scope` be visible inside `updateData`?

**PS.** `angular` version is `1.6.5`

**UPDATE.** I've change directive name from `form` to `formL` into above template. `form` is definetelly not the best name for a dirrective, but it's not the name I have in project, it's a bad simplification of the name for this question. So the problem is not caused by the name of dirrective

Comment: I'm not sure, but "var" could be a reserved keyword. Try using another variable name.

Comment: @m1crdy no, as object attribute its absolutely ok to use `var`.

Comment: rename `.directive('form',...` to something else, since directives can take form of `<ANY> </ANY>`, making `<form>` your directive

Comment: By the way since you've been using latest AngularJS version it would be more convenient to use [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)  for this purpose.

Comment: definitely not the problem with module dependency? `angular.module('app')`  -  `angular.module('app', [])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is your directive element matching. It's an infinite loop because your directive template also includes the directive element `form`. So your directive getting binded again and again and again.

Please check this runnable **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bx8eo69L/)** and rename your directive element. Do not use `form` or modify your template and outsource the `form` element. You also do not need to define a `ng-controller` inside your form element, while your controller is defined by the directive near `controller: 'formCtrl'`.

#### View

```
<div>
   <my-form></my-form>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('formCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.btn = 'BTN';

    $scope.updateData = function () {
       $scope.btn = 'BTN clicked';
    }
});

myApp.directive('myForm', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<form class="form-horizontal"><input type="button" ng-value="btn" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateData()"></form>',
      controller: 'formCtrl'
    }
});
```

#### Update due to question update:

`$scope` is available inside your `$scope` function `updateData()`. Please compare your solution which mine above.
`

Comment: I came up to the same conclusion but the weird thing is that it should be throwing some errors while using the reserved directive name **form** but @Eugeny89 doesn't reference such thing.

Comment: @Korte it does throw an error. I think Eugeny89 did not take a look in the console. =)

Comment: Yes I just noticed the same thing at a fiddle I was preparing but I tought something else was going on. Cheers

Comment: I've updated the question. `form` is definetelly not the best name for a dirrective, but it's not the name I have in project, it's a bad simplification of the name for this question. So the problem is not caused by the name of dirrective

Comment: @Eugeny89 I updated my answer. It should work for you. Please compare your solution with mine. Are there any errors thrown? Please check your console.

Comment: @lin your solution helped. but the thing here is that if I have only `debugger` then `$scope` is `undefined` but if I put `$scope.btn = 'BTN clicked';` there `$scope` is not undefined! Have you an idea what can cause the problem?